# Web Scraping - Problems with tags

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbytagname

I am new scraping web data and also using For...Next. I am trying to get data (all pages) from a website but it seems the code is wrong, since I get error 91. This is the code:

```
Dim ie As Object

Sub connect()
Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
ie.NAVIGATE "https://www.worldathletics.org/world-rankings/100m/men"
ie.Visible = True
End Sub

Sub id_tr_td_for()

Range("a1:z10000").ClearContents

For i = 0 To 10
For j = 0 To 5
Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = ie.document.getElementById("toplists").getElementsByTagName("tr")(i).getElementsByTagName("td")(j).innerText
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Can somebody help me with it and also to let me know who can I list all pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the error comes from, I got it too.

<strike>The following code should be helpful, it will print the contents of the table for the specified page(s) to the debug window.</strike>

The following code should copy all the data for selected pages to sheet1

You will need to Add a couple of references in the VBA Editor to be able to use it. (Tools Menu, References and then find and select them) `Microsoft HTML Object Library` and `Microsoft Internet Controls`

```
Const MaxPage = 2 ' set to 26 (or however many there are) - at 2 for testing purposes
Dim Browser As InternetExplorer

Sub Start()
Dim Page As Integer: Page = 1 ' start at page 1
Dim PageDocument As IHTMLDocument
Dim RecordRow As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim RecordItem As IHTMLElement

Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' output sheet
If Browser Is Nothing Then
    Set Browser = New InternetExplorer
End If
Dim oRow As Integer: oRow = 2 ' begin output at row 2 (account for header)
Dim Record As Integer
For Page = 1 To MaxPage
    LoadPage Page
        For Record = 0 To 99 ' zero index, 100 items (1-99)
        Set PageDocument = Browser.Document
        Set RecordRow = PageDocument.getElementById("toplists").getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(Record).getElementsByTagName("td")
        Sheet.Cells(oRow, 1).Value = Trim(RecordRow(0).innerText)
        Sheet.Cells(oRow, 2).Value = Trim(RecordRow(1).innerText)
        Sheet.Cells(oRow, 3).Value = Trim(RecordRow(2).innerText)
        Sheet.Cells(oRow, 4).Value = Trim(RecordRow(3).innerText)
        Sheet.Cells(oRow, 5).Value = Trim(RecordRow(4).innerText)
        Sheet.Cells(oRow, 6).Value = Trim(RecordRow(5).innerText)
        oRow = oRow + 1
    Next Record
Next Page
Browser.Quit
End Sub

Sub LoadPage(ByVal PageNumber As Integer)
Debug.Print "Navigating to Page #" & CStr(PageNumber)
Browser.navigate "https://www.worldathletics.org/world-rankings/100m/men?page=" & CStr(PageNumber)
While Browser.readyState <> 4 Or Browser.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
Debug.Print "Navigation Complete"
End Sub
```

**Updated Code**

The Index Out-of-Bound error likely occurred due to the hard-coded indexes, if a page does not have 99 records it will fail, if a record doesn't have 5 fields, it will fail. The following code does away with indexes and just scrapes every row and cell it finds. You shouldn't get index errors but the output could be jagged.

**Further Update**

The 462 error was caused by the `Browser.Quit`. This closes the browser but does not set the reference to `Nothing` so when you run the code again it is trying to use a non-existent browser. Explicitly setting it to nothing at the end fixes this.

There is no link in the competitor column, the whole row has a data-url which is handled by something else. That URL can easily be accessed though.

```
Sub NewStart()
Dim PageDocument As IHTMLDocument

Dim Records As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Record As IHTMLElement
Dim RecordItems As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim RecordItem As IHTMLElement

Dim OutputRow As Integer: OutputRow = 2
Dim OutputColumn As Integer

Dim Page As Integer

Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
If Browser Is Nothing Then
    Set Browser = New InternetExplorer
    Browser.Visible = True
End If
For Page = 1 To MaxPage
    LoadPage Page
    Set PageDocument = Browser.Document
    Set Records = PageDocument.getElementById("toplists").getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each Record In Records
        Set RecordItems = Record.getElementsByTagName("td")
        OutputColumn = 1
        For Each RecordItem In RecordItems
            Sheet.Cells(OutputRow, OutputColumn).Value = Trim(RecordItem.innerText)
            OutputColumn = OutputColumn + 1
        Next RecordItem
        Sheet.Cells(OutputRow, OutputColumn).Value = "http://worldathletics.org/" & Record.getAttribute("data-athlete-url") ' This will add the link after the last column
        OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
    Next Record
Next Page
Browser.Quit
Set Browser = Nothing ' This will fix the 462 error
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works very well. Since the problem arised when trying to display the results in a sheet (separated fields), it would be very useful if you could help me with it. Many thanks again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code edition you made. I copied it and I added the two references you mentioned but now I get an error saying the index is out of range.

Comment: @CarlosFC please see the updated code block which should explain/fix that issue.

Comment: Thanks again. It works well now. Just a couple of questions. After executing the macro, if I want to do it again, I get error 462, saying the server doesn't exist or it's not available. If I close and I open the file again it works. Even if I just re type some character of the code. On the other hand, how could I nest a new For Next to do different events from a list: 100m, 200m, 400m, etc). I assume I would need to define a new variable (event) and then to modify the url: https://www.worldathletics.org/world-rankings/"&event&"&m/men?page=" & CStr(PageNumber).

Comment: You could have the URL as a parameter to `NewStart()` and call it for each URL assuming the page format is the same. I'm not sure about the error and can't test at the moment, it could be the server throttling you though. Adding something to slow the requests may help. Might want to browse their ToS first.

Comment: Thanks again Nick. Just a last question. It's about nesting as well but not sure about how to do it. The column "Competitor" is a link, therefore it has a tag "a" that contains athlete's codes, How could I place two more columns with href attribute and innertext?